# Increment counter based on condition in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0, xalan

How Can I increment the counter based on condition and use that counter to test another condition and render some statement?
Here is my input XML -

```
<order>
            <orderId>Order1</orderId>
            <OrderObject>
                <OrderType>30</OrderType>
                <ObjectID>obj1</ObjectID>
            </OrderObject>
            <OrderObject>
                <OrderType>30</OrderType>
                <ObjectID>obj2</ObjectID>
            </OrderObject>
            <OrderObject>
                <OrderType>40</OrderType>
                <ObjectID>obj3</ObjectID>
            </OrderObject>
</order>
```

This is the XSLT what I am trying -

```
<xsl:variable name="counter" select="'1'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="length" select="'5'"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="order/OrderObject">
             <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="OrderType='30">
                                    {
                                     ObjectId : <xsl:value-of select="ObjectID"/>
                                    }
                                    counter = $counter+1;
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="$counter < $length">
                                      <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                                    
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                                    
                                </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Expected Output-

```
                            {
                            
                                    "ObjectId": "obj1"   
                            };
                            {
                            
                                    "ObjectId": "obj2"
                            }
```

Comment: Try to describe your problem in terms of the input and output, not in terms of the approach you would use in a procedural programming language. Functional and declarative programming languages demand a different approach. "Incrementing counters" is intrinsically procedural.

Answer (score 1):

Just process e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="order/OrderObject[OrderType = 30]">`, then inside you can check `position() &lt; 5`.

An alternative approach is not to suffix any but the last item with `;` but to prefix any but the first item:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="order/OrderObject[OrderType = 30]">
     <xsl:if test="position() > 1">;</xsl:if>
     ...
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Also, don't use `xsl:choose` where `xsl:if` will suffice.